# I cannot seem to find a physical machine, trying to look virtually instead

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10

Long story short, we can't find one of our machines that are on the network

It has a computer account but no DNS entry (ageing is set to just over a month), can't ping it, can't c$ onto it, can't find it by running a device scan on our production network.

Is anyone aware of any other ways to find the machine, short of disabling the computer account and waiting for someone to complain? (would prefer not to do that as it's a little messy..)

Cheers

Comment: Most managed switches are able to identify what port a particular MAC address is associated with. have you given that a go?

Comment: What sort of a device scan is that that couldn't find it, is it based on IP/DNS naming, or NetBIOS, or...? Also, do you have a log of when the computer account was last accessed?

Comment: The problem is I don't have the MAC address so won't be able to try that.

The scans that I ran are IP/DNS scans - also I just checked when the computer was last accessed and apparently it's the 5th of April this year, so nearly 4 months ago, I also can't find anything in the security logs, no log on attempts etc.. doesn't seem like it's being used...